# set height of inner div of table-cell to 100% of table-cell height in IE9/10

Tags: html, css

I think this is an IE9/10 specific issue.  I'm trying to create a flexible row layout as follows:

```
|----------------------------------|
|    FIXED HEIGHT                  |
|----------------------------------|
|    FIXED HEIGHT, SOMETIMES HIDDEN|
|----------------------------------|
|                                  |
|    FLEXIBLE HEIGHT               |
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
|    FIXED HEIGHT                  |
|----------------------------------|
```

I also want the outer container for this to have a flexible height and width which fits the browser view port.

Naively, possibly, I thought that since I'm only supporting Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE9/10, then `display: table`, `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell` might be a good way to go, so I came up with:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nugps/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stage">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content1">one</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content1">two</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flexible">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content2">three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content1">four</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.stage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}

.row.flexible {
    height: 100%;
}

.row.flexible .cell {
    height: 100%;
}

.content2 {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100%; /* setting this in IE causes the content to be 100% of the table rather than the table cell height */
}
```

If you open this jsFiddle in Chrome, everything is as expected.  However in IE10, and I suspect IE9 also, the heights are messed up (the .content2 height is 100% of the table rather than the cell).

Is there a good workaround for this other than setting the height of the content manually using javascript?  Or is there a better CSS layout that I could use?  I can't use the newer flexbox because of IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if the content2 class really needs styling, could you not just add the background colour to .row.flexible .cell and get rid of the .content2 style all together.

Here is my solution:
http://cdpn.io/Ewrsa

It works in both IE9/10